# Why add 1 when allocating space for strlen of an array of characters?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, strlen

I am currently working on a program which involves creating a template for an exam.
In the function where I allow the user to add a question to the exam, I am required to ensure that I use only as much memory as is required to store it's data. I've managed to do so after a great deal of research into the differences between various input functions (getc, scanf, etc), and my program seems to be working but I am concerned about one thing. Here is the code for my function, I've placed a comment on the line in question:

```
int AddQuestion(){

Question* newQ = NULL;
char tempQuestion[500];
char* newQuestion;

if(exam.phead == NULL){
    exam.phead = (Question*)malloc(sizeof(Question));
}
else{
    newQ = (Question*)malloc(sizeof(Question));
    newQ->pNext = exam.phead;
    exam.phead = newQ;
}

while(getchar() != '\n');

puts("Add a new question.\n"
     "Please enter the question text below:");
fgets(tempQuestion, 500, stdin);

newQuestion = (char*)malloc(strlen(tempQuestion) + 1); /*Here is where I get confused*/
strcpy(newQuestion, tempQuestion);

fputs(newQuestion, stdout);
puts("Done!");

return 0;
}
```

What's confusing me is that I've tried running the same code but with small changes to test exactly what is going on behind the scenes. I tried removing the + 1 from my `malloc`, which I put there because `strlen` only counts up to but not including the terminating character and I assume that I want the terminating character included. That still ran without a hitch. So I tried running it but with - 1 instead under the impression that doing so would remove whatever is before the terminating character (newline character, correct?). Still, it displayed everything on separate lines.
So now I'm somewhat baffled and doubting my knowledge of how character arrays work. Could anybody help clear up what's going on here, or perhaps provide me with a resource which explains this all in further detail?

Comment: Lots of code and background, but no language tag?

Comment: Overflowing the buffer triggers undefined behavior, which means that anything is allowed to happen. You corrupted memory and got away with it this time. Next time you may not be so lucky.

Comment: @RaymondChen Could you elaborate on when exactly I overflow the buffer?

Comment: @Jongware My mistake, I'll remember to do so in the future.

Comment: You said so yourself. You allocated too little space for the strcpy.

Comment: @RaymondChen ah yeah in that case I definitely did, I just didn't understand why even though I was allocating not enough space it still managed to store the entire string. Basically I was just messing around to see if by allocating not enough space I could remove the '\n' from the original string. Not sure why I just wanted to see if it was possible.

Answer (score 6):

In C, strings are conventionally null-terminated. `Strlen`, however, only counts the characters before the null. So, you always must add one to the value of `strlen` to get enough space. Or call `strdup`.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that I had to add + 1 in the first place, but what I'm wondering is why the program seemed to run the exact same when I tested what would happen if I did NOT add + 1 (I even tried seeing what would happen if I did strlen(tempQuestion) - 5, same output

Comment: @brocode You get lucky since `fgets` always null-terminates the buffer it is given. You tell `fgets` that it has 500 chars to work with, but it will only use 500-1=499 of them at most, saving the last char for the null terminator. Of course, if you type fewer than 499 chars, it will write the null terminator after the newline char (or whatever the last char in the line is if it isn't a newline).

Answer (score 1):

A C string contains the characters you can see "abc" plus one you can't which marks the end of the string.  You represent this as '\0'.   The strlen function uses the '\0' to find the end of the string, but doesn't count it.

So

```
myvar = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

is correct.   However, what you tried:

```
myvar = malloc(strlen(str));
```

and

```
myvar = malloc(strlen(str) - 1);
```

while INCORRECT, *MAY* seem to work some of the time.   This is because malloc typically allocates memory in chunks, (say maybe in units of 16 bytes) rather than the exact size you ask for.  So sometimes, you may 'luck out' and end up using the 'slop' at the end of the chunk.

Comment: Ah I understand now, thanks! Since I've already posted it, does the rest of the code seem alright? I spent all day trying to decide on a way of receiving input from the user before settling on fgets, do you have any caveats as far as that goes?

Comment: fgets() is a reasonable way to read input.  some caveats, it includes the newline (return key) and if the line typed is longer than the space you give it then your input can be truncated.   The top part of your code (dealing with newQ) doesn't seem to relate to the part where you read the question, though.

Comment: Thanks, that top part I suppose had not been completed I still needed to point the char* within my Question struct (didn't bother pasting that part of my code, it would have been unnecessary for the question) to the newQuestion. I just got super sidetracked when I tried testing if I could basically remove the '\n' from the string if I reduced the amount of space that I was copying to. Now I know not to try that! (In any case I do want the newline in my output, was merely tinkering around a bit.)

Comment: @brocode On the subject of the newline appended by `fgets()`.  Even if you don't want to remove it, finding it will tell you that the input was not truncated.  `if (fgets(tempQuestion, sizeof(tempQuestion), stdin) == NULL) { /* no more input or error */ } else if (tempQuestion[strlen(tempQuestion)-1] != '\n') { /* input was truncated */ } else { /* good input*/ }`  There are a couple of corner cases where that code isn't quite correct, but you won't run into them reading from the terminal, so I left out the additional complexity of dealing with them.

Answer (score 0):

C strings are terminated by a null character `'\0'`. When calling `strlen` on a string, it only counts the characters until it reaches the null terminator (it doesn't count the null terminator itself).

So for example if you do:

```
const char *example = "Hello!";
char *s = calloc(strlen(example), sizeof(char));
printf("%s\n", s);
```

Then the string `s` would be allocated (it would look something like this in memory):

```
'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!'
```

But C strings need to be null terminated, so we allocate the extra byte reserved for the null terminator `'\0'`.

Comment: Does this add anything to the others answers, posted some 9 years ago?